# Web Scraping - I cannot use a for loop to list element

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, scrapy

i am currently building a web scraper and i encountered a problem.
When i try to build my for loop in order to regroup all information by company the extraction keeps on showing all elements of the same type together.

When I realized that it didnt work i went back and tried to show an index list of only the first element but even when I type [0] all the elements are shown to me as if no specific selection was made

```
import scrapy
from centech.items import CentechItem

class CentechSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'centech_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://centech.co/nos-entreprises/']

    def parse(self, response):
       items = CentechItem()
       all_companies = response.xpath("//div[@class = 'fl-post-carousel- 
    post']")[1]    #   "//div[@class = 'fl-post-carousel-post']")[1]
    Nom = all_companies.xpath("//h2[contains(@class, 'fl-post-carousel- 
    title')]/text()").extract()
    Description = all_companies.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 
    'description')]/p/text()").extract()
    # Nom = all_companies.response.css("h2.fl-post-carousel- 
    title::text").extract()
    # Description = all_companies.xpath("p::text").extract()

    yield {'Nom' : Nom ,
           'Description' : Description ,
           }
```

I expect to see only the first element of the page but all the entreprises are shown.

Thank you.

Comment: u can add id in the xpath also to uniquely identify it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about the output you wish to have. I took a guess and modified your script to grab the following results. You need to go one layer deep to fetch the full description as some of the description are broken:

```
import scrapy

class CentechSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'centech_spider'
    start_urls = ['https://centech.co/nos-entreprises/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css("a.fl-post-carousel-link"):
            nom = item.css(".description > h2.fl-post-carousel-title::text").get()
            description = item.css(".description > p::text").get()
            yield {'nom':nom,'description':description}
```